# How to access constant string in runtime using a string which holding its name?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I have some constant strings defined in my @implementation file like:

```
static NSString * const contentDisplayDateKeyPath   = @"content.display_date";
static NSString * const contentIDKeyPath            = @"content.id";
```

Could I get the content of contentDisplayDateKeyPath use a string which holding the variable's name in runtime?

ex:

```
NSString *constantName = @"contentDisplayDateKeyPath"

[self valueForKey:constantName]
```

then I'll get content.display_date

Can this be achieved?

I am trying to achieve this by using CFBundleGetDataPointer

```
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier(CFBridgingRetain([[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]));
    void *stringPointer = CFBundleGetDataPointerForName(mainBundle, CFBridgingRetain(obj));
    NSString *string = (__bridge NSString *)stringPointer;
```

But the stringPointer is always null.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a map with the key as the constant name and the value as the constant value:

```
static NSDictionary *_constants = @{

    @"contentDisplayDateKeyPath" : @"content.display_date",
    @"contentIDKeyPath"          : @"content.id",
    // etc.
};

...

NSString *constantName = @"contentDisplayDateKeyPath";
NSString *constantValue = _constants[constantName];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already try your suggestion and this completely fulfills my needs. But I'm looking for another solution (like using CFBundleGetDataPointerForName)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you.

```
NSString *__autoreleasing *string = (NSString*__autoreleasing*)dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "<name of constant like PKPaymentNetworkVisa>");
NSLog(@"%@", *string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to encapsulate this into a singleton object and access your constants through read only properties.  Check out [What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like) to see the singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here:

> [How do I lookup a string constant at runtime in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289301/how-do-i-lookup-a-string-constant-at-runtime-in-objective-c)

The solution worked perfectly for me.

You can use `CFBundleGetDataPointerForName` to lookup a constant's value at runtime

```
-(NSString *)lookupStringConstant:(NSString *)constantName 
{

    void ** dataPtr = CFBundleGetDataPointerForName(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), (__bridge CFStringRef)constantName);
    return (__bridge NSString *)(dataPtr ? *dataPtr : nil);
}
```