# How do I lookup a string constant at runtime in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

My company develops an advertising SDK that mediates other ad networks. At runtime, it checks if the other ad networks are present by using `NSClassFromString`, and sends those classes messages if they're present.

This works fine for Objective-C objects, but how can I load a string constant at runtime? In this case, I want to check the version of an SDK that is only available through a string constant (`extern NSString* VungleSDKVersion;`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `CFBundleGetDataPointerForName` to lookup a constant's value at runtime

```
NSString *lookupStringConstant(NSString *constantName) {
    void ** dataPtr = CFBundleGetDataPointerForName(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), (__bridge CFStringRef)constantName);
    return (__bridge NSString *)(dataPtr ? *dataPtr : nil);
}
```

Example use:

```
NSString *version = lookupStringConstant(@"VungleSDKVersion");
NSLog(@"Version = %@",version);
```

Comment: This is years after the fact, but I wanted to add this wasn't 100% reliable at the time. It seemed to work fine in most cases, but some apps compiled from 3rd party tools seemed to have it fail. I assume some sort of stripping of the metadata causes that? Not sure.