# Why doesn't CFBundleGetDataPointerForName work for iOS 8-style frameworks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

Typically in iOS you can [load constants at runtime using `CFBundleGetDataPointerForName`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26289302/1176156). However, I'm finding that `CFBundleGetDataPointerForName` always returns `NULL` pointers for constants defined in iOS-8 style frameworks, like the ones discussed in [WWDC 2014 Session 416: Building Modern Frameworks](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/416).

To replicate, I'm just creating a framework with the Xcode framework template, adding a build script to make a universal binary, and dragging the created framework into another project has the framework project. Then I try to load a constant from it like so:

```
void * versionNumberConstant = CFBundleGetDataPointerForName(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("TestFramework2VersionNumber"));
NSLog(@"Version number was %@",versionNumberConstant ? @"PRESENT" : @"NULL"); // Prints NULL
```

For replication purposes, [this repo](https://github.com/MaxGabriel/iOS8Framework) has the framework project, and [this repo](https://github.com/MaxGabriel/iOS8FrameworkGetDataPointer) tries to load a constant from that framework using `CFBundleGetDataPointerForName`. 
I can also replicate this issue with frameworks other developers have made, such as [AdMob's SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download).

Just in case its an issue with the pointer not being in `CFBundleGetMainBundle()`, I've also looped through every `CFBundleRef` and can't load the constant from any of them:

```
CFArrayRef array = CFBundleGetAllBundles();
for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(array); i++) {
    CFBundleRef bundleRef = (CFBundleRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(array, i);
    void * versionPointer = CFBundleGetDataPointerForName(bundleRef, CFSTR("TestFramework2VersionNumber"));
    NSLog(@"Version pointer is %@",versionPointer ? @"PRESENT" : @"NULL");
}
```

Does anyone know why this is, or if there's some build setting I can change to fix it?

Version info:

- Xcode: Version 6.2 6C131e
- iOS: 8.2 (12D508)
- Device: iPhone 6 / iPhone 6 Simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was that I needed to load the specific bundle that that framework was using, like so:

```
NSURL *testFramework2URL = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Frameworks" isDirectory:YES] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestFramework2.framework"];

CFBundleRef bundleRef = CFBundleCreate(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef)testFramework2URL);
NSLog(@"Bundle Ref = %@",bundleRef);

double * manualVersion = CFBundleGetDataPointerForName(bundleRef, CFSTR("TestFramework2VersionNumber"));
NSLog(@"Manual version = %@",manualVersion ? @"present" : @"NULL"); // Manual version = present

double version = *manualVersion;
NSLog(@"Version = %g",version); // Version = 1
```

I can also achieve this using `CFBundleGetAllBundles()`, despite what I said in the question (I must have made a mistake when originally using the `CFBundleGetAllBundles()` function or something.